# Ant Design - How to do something on cancel of Upload?

Tags: javascript, antd

How can I do something when the user click on the Button then "cancel" ?

We have `onChange` to do something when an image is uploaded, but nothing when the user cancel on the modal.

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/xyjxln?file=/demo.tsx

Doc for Upload: https://ant.design/components/upload